# Why are there no minimum wage entry level IT jobs

Tags: labor-economics, united-kingdom

In the UK, I have not seen any graduate level IT jobs offering a starting salary below £20,000. At the same time, about 10% of computer science graduates are unemployed six months after graduation. Also, a significant proportion of computer science graduates end up in minimum wage jobs that do not use their skills and would prefer to work in the IT sector even if their pay remained the same.

Why are there no minimum wage graduate level IT jobs? If there are job candidates whose labour is worth more than £20k a year, and there are candidates who are not worth employing even at minimum wage, then surely there must be candidates whose labour is worth less than £20k but more than minimum wage?
https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/07/22/computer_science_graduates_hesa_employment/

Comment: I think there's a fallacy in your logic here.  Can we assume that most people could get a minimum wage job after having a degree?  Most employers will assume that you'll leave in short order once you can get something more in line with your qualifications.  It seems like you're asking for the job equivalent of a [unicorn hire](https://www.thiswayglobal.com/blog/qualities-of-top-talents-and-how-to-attract-them/).

Comment: Is it typical for any university graduate in the UK to be offered less than £20,000?